# Save whole logcat to device

Tags: android, logcat

I know there are quite a lot of similar questions but I (hopefully) checked all of them.

**My questions is:** How can I save the **whole** logcat to my device? Currently I'm running `logcat -d` but this only gives me loggings belonging to my app. What I need is the whole logcat as if I would call `adb logcat -d > logcat.txt` from my host PC. When I do this from my PC I get a huge file but when running on my device I only get a small file. I also tried `logcat -f` but it didn't save anything to my device.

And yes, I'm using
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />` and root permissions.

Comment: Root does not have anything directly to do with it. Your app needs to be installed on the system partition to hold `READ_LOGS`, and you can perhaps accomplish that via root. But it is not like simply having a rooted device magically will give you that permission. If the small file just has your own log messages, and not those from other processes, not actually having `READ_LOGS` is the likely source of your difficulty.

Comment: I just said I have root so that the reader knows I'm not limited in that area. So how are apps like Catlog doing this? Are they installed on /system?

Comment: "Are they installed on /system?" -- presumably, at least on API Level 16+ devices.

Comment: Okay, so I guess I have no chance in getting the log then... It would have been nice to automatically attach a logcat to the email if a user chooses to send in a bug report.

Comment: FWIW, I have more on the `READ_LOGS` situation in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html).

Comment: Okay thank you, Sir! I'll have to live with it. Sadly only a few users are able to provide logcats themself.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this from your host pc adb logcat -d > logcat.txt  it will save all the logs

on windows machine:

To get only the logs related to your app just do

```
    adb logcat | find "package name of your app" > logfile.txt
```

to get the logs with the time values

```
    adb logcat -v time | find "package name of your app" > logfile.txt
```

you can either provide package name or PID.

For linux use grep instead find.

if you are using android studio, install debug app in your phone it will show the logs for your package name only

May be this answer is helpful